# Common-output WS2812 LED strip alternative control

Tags: raspberry-pi, level-shifting, open-drain, attiny85, ws2812b

I try to build an RPi controlled LED strip, however, while the Linux is booting, I still want a minimal effect on the LED strip. So my idea is that once the device gets voltage, a cheap microcontroller (Attiny85) would control the LED strip.

On the one hand, a level shifter would be necessary (3V3 RPi -> 5V WS2812). On the other hand, as soon as the Raspberry Pi sends a signal (on a different pin) to the microcontroller (Attiny85), it should disconnect from the line, and let RPi to take the control.
So my question is:
In the white box with the question mark, what kind of circuit should I build?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to control strip by Attiny and Attiny communicate with Raspberry?

Comment: A level shifter that doesn't need you to connect the ports. I think *Low-power configurable multiple function gates* usable *as translators in mixed 3.3 V and 5 V environments* nice, a 74LVC1G97 just an example.

Comment: @user263983 not exactly. I want to control the same LED strip alternately with Atiny and RPi.

Comment: Thanks @greybeard, am I rigth that I should use the 2-to-1 data selector logic function?

Comment: Using the data selector function would require a *select signal*. I'd go for *OR*. I guess I'd add a pull down to each "MCU signal" so it works even if one is not powered. (I mention a configurable gate because that's most useful in a tinkerer's drawer. And yes, it's still possible to use a "diode-or".)